# Multiple #ifndef statements - which one gets applied

Tags: c, gcc, ifndef

Say I have five files: `main.c, sample1.c, sample1.h, sample2.c` and `sample2.h`, where in each of these files `DEBUG_PRINTS` is defined as follows:

```
#ifndef DEBUG_PRINTS
#define DEBUG_PRINTS 0
#endif
```

and the code is compiled using gcc:

```
gcc -Wall main.c sample1.c sample2.c -o main
```

Now I change the value of `DEBUG_PRINTS` in one file to `1`. Without printing to the terminal how can you determine, which value will be applied?

Additionally, how can I define `DEBUG_PRINTS` locally per file - the same as using the `static` keyword for variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each file is compiled separately. Macros from one file are not visible in any other file. Once the files are independently compiled, the resulting objects are linked together to create an executable.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: the compiler first defines the macros listed in a source file, then it imports all macros from the first included header file, after that the second header file and so on. In this order it will apply the first definition of DEBUG_PRINTS it comes across and all other #ifndef (in the subsequent header files) will be escaped.

Comment: No. The compiler reads the file in order. When it sees a `#define` it defines the macro. When it sees a `#include` it reads the included file. Just a single pass. While it does that if it sees a macro which is currrntly defined, it uses the current definition. (You csn unset a macro with `#undef` and later redefine it. So order matters.)

Comment: @alexander, it is correct that in this case the definition of `DEBUG_PRINTS` in the first included file will "win", unless you define the symbol in the main file *before* the includes.

Answer (score 1):

`#ifndef` means if the macro *isn't defined at all* in that file before or in an header you included. In your case, it defaults to 0.

If you change `DEBUG_PRINTS` in that one file to `1`, it will override that `#define` in `#ifndef` found in the header file. You are basically locally defining or overriding the default `DEBUG_PRINTS` in the imported header file to `1`.

Otherwise, macros are visible only to this file  or header.